# handling file not found exception?

Tags: c#-4.0

I made this code to empty some files that I regularly delete, such as temp files in Windows.  Several friends may wish to use the same application and I am working on the best way to handle the file not found exception.

How can this best be handled for use by multiple users?

```
public void Deletefiles()
    {
        try
        {                
            string[] DirectoryList = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\1");
            string[] FileList = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\1");

            foreach (string x in DirectoryList)
            {
                Directory.Delete(x, true);
                FoldersCounter++;
            }

            foreach (string y in FileList)
            {
                File.Delete(y);
                FilesCounter++;
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Done...\nFiles deleted - " + FileList.Length + "\nDirectories deleted - " + DirectoryList.Length + "\n" + FilesCounter + "\n", "message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }

        catch (Exception z)
        {
            if (z.Message.Contains("NotFound"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File Not Found");
            }
            else
            {
                throw (z);
            }
            //throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying you code as little as possible, you could simply wrap your `Delete` calls in a try/catch:

```
foreach (string x in DirectoryList)
{
    try {
        Directory.Delete(x, true);
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
    {
        // do something, or not...
    }
    FoldersCounter++;
}

foreach (string y in FileList)
{
    try
    {
        File.Delete(y);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        // do something, or not...
    }
    FilesCounter++;
}
```

Remove the top level try/catch and just let the `foreach` statements cycle through -- `try`ing and `catch`ing any exceptions as they come.

You don't necessarily need to alert the user that the file wasn't found.  It is there it is going to be deleted, so the fact that it isn't there doesn't really effect the outcome of the program.

This isn't the most resource friendly method, but it is a simple enough application to not cause an issue.

Comment: yea I do not want user to be alert if there is no such file and that's what I want to know how get through using try catch...
without the try catch the code will throw an exception... and teach me how to make friendly  if you can please ?

Comment: I want to know what should be written in the catch section to avoid users from getting exception in that case and keep my program keep going...

Comment: @xXghostXx Sounds like you don't need to write anything in there, since you don't want to do anything. Just leave a commented line explaining that you specifically want to 'do nothing', so you know in the future why you left that `catch(FileNotFoundException e)` block blank.

Comment: What I wrote will do what you want.  Remove the try/catch that you currently have and replace the `foreach` loops with the ones I posted.  The user will never know an exception was thrown.

Comment: @Evil Closet Monkey i did replace it as u suggest of course is better than I did man... and when leave blank its throw that exception https://www.dropbox.com/s/01sok50cz0gmm9r/1.PNG

Comment: @Andrew Barber take alook at the comment above please

Comment: @xXghostXx You have another exception, then. You need to examine what the exception actually occurring is.

Comment: @Andrew Barber I don't think so cause this message only appears when the I delete the folder "1" in the specified folder